# SpriteRenderer.Color && Colider Interact

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a map that contains several regions
 I selected a region and it was colored.
All I want to do is when I select another region that has recently selected to fade and color the one I select
This is the code used to color a region

```
targetIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(Maps, target);
Maps[targetIndex].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.gray;
```

Comment: are you saying that you want the region color to lerp from grey to another selected color?

Answer (score 0):

Add two indexes. Lets call them `currentlySelectedIndex` and `previouslySelectedIndex`.

At the beginnig these two will be pointing the first object because there is no previously selected region.

When you make the second or further selection, you will assing your `currentlySelectedIndex` to newly selected region, but `previouslySelectedIndex` will still pointing the old region.

At this point you will use `previouslySelectedIndex` like you did when coloring the region. After coloring the old region is completed, you will assign `previouslySelectedIndex` as `currentlySelectedIndex`. And this will carry on.

> Pseudo

```
//Check if its the first time Selection

currentlySelectedIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(Maps, target);
Maps[currentlySelectedIndex].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.gray;
previouslySelectedIndex = currentlySelectedIndex;

//After the first time selection

currentlySelectedIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(Maps, target); //New Selected Region
Maps[currentlySelectedIndex].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.gray;
Maps[previouslySelectedIndex].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = FadeColor; //Old Selected Region
previouslySelectedIndex = currentlySelectedIndex;
```